# C: Forward declaring a typedef that will be defined later for being used in declaring a function now

Tags: c, typedef, forward-declaration

**So..** I got a bit of a chicken and egg thing going on.

I got Controller_setup.h and Equipment_setup.h which use typedefs defined in the other.  I could write a whole lot here about justifying why this is but will refrain from doing so unless someone really really wants to know (though basically it was an attempt to have the code in Equipment_setup.c/h work with different controller systems simply by having a different Controller_setup.h).

On the previous controller and compiler (controller used an ARM processor and we were using the IAR compiler and IDE) we developed the code on I was able to forward declare/redefine the typedefs and it would work.  It would give us lots of warnings but it would compile and work.

Now that we are actually trying to port over to another controller using another IDE and compiler (controller uses a TriCore processor and we are using the Code::blocks IDE with GNU GCC compiler for TriCore V3.4.6) it's now raising errors and won't let the code compile.

I am very new to this, but from what I understood I should be able to at any time put a declaration saying that this datatype is defined somewhere so the compiler shouldn't worry when I reference that datatype in my function declarations.

Since it worked on one compiler (admittedly with warnings) I am hoping that there is some way to make it work now.  I don't suppose it's something as simple as using a different syntax is it?  Is it possible to declare a typedef vs redefining it?

Actually I just googled that exact question and by following that trail I seem to now understand that what I want to do is allowed under C11, but not previous C standards.  And as far as I can tell the Tricore compiler doesn't support C11 so this is likely why it used to work but not now.

But if someone could help verify this understanding that would be appreciated.

I really don't want to have to find a work around as I fear it may mean a fairly substantial rework of how the program is structured.  It would likely be better in the long run, but now is not a good time to have to do it.

Below is a simplified version of what had worked but not now.  I have left out the parts where Controller_setup.h is referencing Equipment_setup.h. When the project is built Equipment_setup.h is read first so I then get the error when the redefinition in Controller_setup.h is read.

The error message is:

> - error: [12993] redefinition of typedef 'IO_link_t'
> - error: [13256] previous declaration of 'IO_link_t' was here

**Equipment_setup.h**

```
//The functions declared here are used by other .c files which
//determine how the equipment is to operate

typedef enum IO_devices_t IO_devices_t;
typedef struct IO_link_t IO_link_t;

//Declare function for checking status of a given IO device
uint8_t check_IO_device_status(IO_device_t device);

//Declare function for calibrating an input
uint8_t calibrate_input(IO_link_t*  input);
```

**Controller_setup.h**

```
typedef enum IO_devices_t{
  MAIN_CONTROLLER,
  REMOTE_IO_1,
  REMOTE_IO_2,
  //... will vary based on controllers being used...
  HMI_1,
  NUMBER_IO_DEVICES
} IO_devices_t;

typedef struct IO_link_t {
  IO_msg_ptr_t          IO_msg_ptr;
  uint8_t               IO_msg_size;
  IO_logic_ptr_t        IO_logic_ptr;
  //... other members as required by Equipment_setup.h ...
  //... members that vary based on the controller's SDK ...
} IO_link_t;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
typedef struct IO_link_t IO_link_t;
```

The `typedef` **defines** a type.  You're also **declaring** `struct IO_link_t`.  When you then do this:

```
typedef struct IO_link_t {
  IO_msg_ptr_t          IO_msg_ptr;
  uint8_t               IO_msg_size;
  IO_logic_ptr_t        IO_logic_ptr;
  //... other members as required by Equipment_setup.h ...
  //... members that vary based on the controller's SDK ...
} IO_link_t;
```

You **define** `struct IO_link_t` which was previously not defined but you also **redefine** the type `IO_link_t`.  That's where the error comes from.  The same goes for the `enum`.

You can fix this by removing the `typedef` at the point the `struct` and `enum` are defined.

```
enum IO_devices_t{
  MAIN_CONTROLLER,
  REMOTE_IO_1,
  REMOTE_IO_2,
  //... will vary based on controllers being used...
  HMI_1,
  NUMBER_IO_DEVICES
};

struct IO_link_t {
  IO_msg_ptr_t          IO_msg_ptr;
  uint8_t               IO_msg_size;
  IO_logic_ptr_t        IO_logic_ptr;
  //... other members as required by Equipment_setup.h ...
  //... members that vary based on the controller's SDK ...
};
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.  If I understand correctly then I would leave my forward declarations (?? is that the right term, I'm thinking not) the same in Equipment_setup.h.  Something that I think matters a lot is the fact (which I forgot to mention) is that there are structs and functions in Controller_setup.h that also use those typedef datatypes.

Comment: But you have helped and I think I'm starting to see the difference between how I think things work and how they actually do.  I had sorta understood typedef was a way to create abreviations in that it was almost like a macro where it saved me from having to type enum or struct at the beginning, but it wasn't really defining anything in itself. But as the name says it is used to define a symbol.

Comment: In my original example you can think of it as in Equipment_setup.h I am defining a declaration where as in Controller_setup.h I am defining a defintion.  So *struct IO_link_t* has one declaration and one defintion which is fine, but *IO_link_t* gets defined in two places which is not.

Comment: So if I am understanding this all correctly, one way around this would be to simply avoid the typedef and simply do a replace all with *struct IO_link_t*??

Comment: @MidnightRover You can keep the `typedef`, just do it in one place only.

Comment: Note that C11 (and C18) allow you to define a `typedef` twice as long as it is identical each tie.  I've not used the feature (knowingly) and have no plans to do so.  However, it exists — see C11 [§6.7 Declarations ¶3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7p3): _a typedef name may be redefined to denote the same type as it currently does, provided that type is not a variably modified type._